# Prevent capistrano to run migration in deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, deployment, migration, database-migration, capistrano3

I am using `capistrano rails gem` in my application. When I run `cap production deploy` it deploys my changes and at the same time it runs my `db:migrate` and runs all my **pending migrations**.

For a testing reason I don't want it to run `db:migrate` after it deploy.

How can I prevent `capistrano` to run `deploy:migrate` when deploying and more importantly how I can see my **migrations status** to see all my **pending migrations** `capistrano` will run.

For instnace in *development ENV* I can just run `rake db:migrate:status` and its shows me which migrations are `up` or `down` and which will/need to run.

*Only `namespace/function` in my `deploy.rb`*

```
namespace :deploy do

  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
    end
  end

  desc "reload the database with seed data"
  task :seed do
    puts "\n=== Seeding Database ===\n"
    on primary :db do
      within current_path do
        with rails_env: fetch(:stage) do
          execute :rake, 'db:seed'
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Rest of my `deploy.rb` has all usual things such as:

`set :application`, `set :repo_url`, `set :passenger_restart_with_touch`, `set :deploy_to`, `set :bundle_binstubs`, `set :linked_files`, `set :linked_dirs`

*My versions:*

`Rails: 4.2.4`

`Capistrano: 3.5`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two ways of initializing the Capistrano-Rails Gem. In your `Capfile`, you can add `require 'capistrano/rails'`, which will generate assets and run migrations, or you can add `require 'capistrano/rails/assets'` and/or `require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'` which will do one or the other, or both if both are included.

So, to not run migrations, make sure that `require 'capistrano/rails'` and `require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'` are not in your Capfile.

Comment: Thanks @will_in_wi